# Apply style to textbox substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple search form consisting of just a textfield, but it has filters (e.g., beginning the query with "type:" only searches a database column of "type"). What I'd like to have is for that text before the actual search term (i.e., "type:") to be styled in such a way that it's obvious to the user that it's a filter and not a search term. In fact, it might look something like StackOverflow's Tags textfield after a user has typed in a tag (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUjXV.png)). So far, I've got a .keypress() method being called on the textfield to determine if the first term is indeed a filter, but I'm not sure how to style the filter text. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find that the SO tag box (and other solutions) actually do not style the content in the input box itself but prepend the tag/filter formatting as a span and adjust the width of the input box accordingly. The input box itself has all the styling removed (so no border or anything), the border is provided by a styled div. 
So you need a structure like this (btw this is a simplified view):

```
<div class="i am a div styled like an input box with a border">
<span class="i am a filter/tag">Type:</span>
<input type="text" class="i am actual input box with all styling removed">
</div>
```

You need to handle adding/removing filters and resizing of the input box (based on the length of the filter tag) as well (if you have only one filter you could probably get away with a fixed width input field)...

Comment: Awesome, didn't think to do this. Thanks!